# How to store PDF files: in sqlite or in the separate folder

Tags: sqlite, windows-8.1, win-universal-app, sqlite-net

I am developing Windows 8.1 Universal Application and I use Sqlite and Sqlite-Net to store the data. Now I need to add ability to store PDF files (1 Mb - 50 Mb) files in my application.

What is the best solution in this case?  Store files in the Sqlite or store them into separate folder?  Which folder will be better to use in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are going to be storing relational data and that you need to run queries (and it sounds like you aren't), **I would suggest using the local storage**. It isn't really that difficult to use.

Now, as far as performance. Reading the disk on the app is not going to be fast. That being said, any solution you use is going to be saved to disk in the end; so I don't think you will notice much of a difference if you go with DB or local storage in terms of performance.

**A good option** would be to store the files on the SD Card/Removable Devices if available, this way all the valuable phone's internal memory will not be used up.